# define EmbeddedDatabaseFactory to load custom EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer on Spring

Tags: java, swing, configuration, h2, spring-jdbc

I wrote a customized H2 EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer to save the location of my db inside the path of my swing application.. the default is created in memory, so I lose data every time I close the application

but how to tell spring to use them in the context.xml ?

i know i need to use a EmbeddedDatabaseFactory to tell the configuration to spring, but I do not know when or in what place I do this in the XML config file..

any ideas?

i followed this link http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch12s08.html item 12.8.4 to reach this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out this blog article: [Integration tests, databases, and the Spring Framework](http://itsthecodestupid.blogspot.com/2011/04/integration-tests-databases-and-spring.html) which describes how to use `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean` to use your
configurer.